# Issues with overriding an ngrx store setup in a test with TestBed.overrideModule

Tags: angular, testing, ngrx

I am testing an angular/NgRx application and I am facing difficulties overriding the `Store` with the angular `TestBed`.

Please note that for the purpose of this test suite, **I cannot rely on the `provideMockStore` utility**. I have to use the actual `Store`.

Here is the global test setup in the top-level describe:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        SmartRecoRecommendationComponent,
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          products: productsReducer,
          ...
        }),
        StoreModule.forFeature(smartRecoFeatureKey, {
          ...fromSmartReco.reducers,
      recommendation: (
        state: {
          products: ProductRecommendation[];
        } | null = smartRecoStateMock.recommendation,
        type: Action
      ) => fromSmartReco.reducers.recommendation(state, type),
        ...
```

Here is how I try to override the `Store import` in a local describe:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
   TestBed.overrideModule(StoreModule, {
    remove: {
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}), StoreModule.forFeature(smartRecoFeatureKey, {})],
    },
    add: {
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          products: productsReducer,
          ...
        }),
        StoreModule.forFeature(smartRecoFeatureKey, {
          ...fromSmartReco.reducers,
          recommendationErrorType: (state: ProductRecommendationErrorTypes = ProductRecommendationErrorTypes.TECHNICAL, type: Action) =>
        }),
      ],
    },
  });
  await TestBed.compileComponents();
  ...
```

However, the `Store` is not overridden by the local setup... Only the global setup is taken into account.

The documentation about overriding providers or modules is scarce and I am not sure what I got wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to override `StoreModule` that comes from the library, is it a typo?

Comment: Hi @Shlang and thanks for your comment. Actually no: I believed it was the way to override the Store config. What should be specified instead of `StoreModule` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestBed.overrideModule` is used for overriding metadata (an object passed to `@NgModule` decorator) of a certain module used for setting up a TestBed. So the call `TestBed.overrideModule(StoreModule, ...)` overrides StoreModule's imports but what you need instead is to override the imports of the module created with `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. It seems that there is no way to do it (more info at the end of the answer), but there are other ways to achieve the same result.

1. Call `TestBed.configureTestingModule` in nested beforeEach or even as part of `it`. That is it, you don't have to have only 1 configuration in the top-level `beforeEach`. The most obvious downside of this approach is that you may have a lot of duplication, but it is always possible to extract `imports`, `providers`, and other parts into arrays, or create your own wrapper around `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
describe('Top Level', () => {
  const commonImports = [
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      products: productsReducer,
      /* ... */
    })
  ];

  describe('Test with feature A', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          ...commonImports,
          StoreModule.forFeature(smartRecoFeatureKey, /* ... */)
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    });
  });
});
```

2. This does not really seem to apply to your case, but just for completeness - it is possible to use `TestBed.override*` methods. For example, `TestBed.overrideProvider` can be used for overriding a provider:

```
describe('Top Level', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Test, useValue: '123' }]
    });
  });

  it(`should have the 'ssr' title`, async () => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(Test, { useValue: '111' });
    expect(TestBed.inject(Test)).toEqual('111');
  });
});
```

This way it should be possible to override certain providers, provided by `StoreModule`, but it may be quite hard to understand what exactly should be overridden, as `StoreModule` [uses a lot of providers](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/092076c20caa698000e1a952f3b3bd4abf69a161/modules/store/src/provide_store.ts#L116).

---

About "It seems that there is no way to do it". Among other things `TestBed.configureTestingModule` does under the hood, it creates a module and a reference to this module is accessible via private fields: `(TestBed as any).INSTANCE.testModuleRef`, but as long as module metadata is passed through a decorator, at the time a reference to a module exists it is too late to override it. Because of the same reason, calls to `TestBed.override*` should be done before the test module is instantiated.